# Polyglot seems not working when using translate function

Tags: admin-on-rest, react-admin

The transalte's polyglot feature don't work (i'm in the last version of react-admin) :

this my language file :

```
export default
{
    "labels": {
        "num_files": "%{count} file |||| %{count} files"
    }
}
```

and how i call the tranlate function :

```
translate('labels.num_files', { count: 5 })
```

and it's shown in my component :

```
5 file |||| 5 files
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Polyglot documentation](http://airbnb.io/polyglot.js/#pluralization), the variable which should be used to determine whether to use the singular or plural form must be named `smart_count`.

This is because you may have multiple variables and polyglot needs to which one to use for pluralization detection.